# string interpolation in Get URI with httparty issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, httparty

So I was using the splunk rest api to generate the search id thorugh post and then get the search results through a get request.

I am using httpparty, & this is my post and get request as follows:

```
  def sid
    self.class.post(
      "/services/search/jobs",
      headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'},
      basic_auth: @auth
    ).parsed_response
  end
```

The generated sid looks like this:

> 1503402217.608

I make the necessary get request as follows:

```
 def results(sid)
   self.class.get(
    "/services/search/jobs/#{sid}/results/",
    headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'text/html'},
    basic_auth: @auth
  )  

 end
```

The above request gives a 204 no content.
However if I manually paste the sid in my code and run it, i get results back.

> for eg: "/services/search/jobs/1503402217.608/results/"

So my question is how can interpolate the above to get results back.

EDIT: my dyamic get request looks this in the console:

```
<- "GET /services/search/jobs/1503402217.608/results/ HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAccept: text/html\r\nAuthorization: Basic something==\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: server:8089\r\n\r\n"
-> "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content\r\n"
-> "Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2017 11:43:37 GMT\r\n"
-> "Expires: Thu, 26 Oct 1978 00:00:00 GMT\r\n"
-> "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0\r\n"
-> "Content-Length: 0\r\n"
-> "Vary: Cookie, Authorization\r\n"
-> "Connection: Close\r\n"
-> "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n"
-> "Server: Splunkd\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
```

EDIT: Just so you know, this how i am parsing the sid in the first place before sending it as an argument to the GET request:

> sid.parsed_response["sid"]

Comment: Just a weird assumption: could you please copy-paste the real `sid` here? It could contain some invisible codepoints.

Comment: @aristotl,yes first example is  a post request which generates the sid and returns it. second. I am parsing the sid and making a second request which is a get

Comment: @mudasobwa,  the above sid is the real sid returned by splunk api

Comment: Can you post the url generated when you use `#{sid}`?

Comment: See my edit in question. I have posted the url generated when interpolate sid.